# Can you access sim contacts from J2ME?

Tags: java-me, mobile, contacts, sim-card

Hi I am developing a mobile application where I need to access the phonebook of the users, SIM and phone contacts.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the handset, some only let you access phone contacts, some do both phone and sim.  Make sure you iterate over all the `PIMList`s supplied by `PIM.listPIMLists()`, often this method returns two lists, one of which will be phone, the other will be sim.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah its possible. Look on [this discussion on Nokia forum.](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?203524-Retrieve-SIM-contacts) Here it will be described clearly about how to get the contacts from phone and sim.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the contacts using the following API

**JSR 75: PDA Optional Packages for the J2METM Platform**

http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=75

This is an optional package & maynot be there for all the mobile devices.

You can check the following URL for the sample programs

1. http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/pim/index.html
2. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2ME/PersonalInformationManager.htm

Use the following code to check whether the device supports PIM or not :

```
String currentVersion = System.getProperty("microedition.pim.version" )
```

if the device  is not supported then it will return `null`.